# How can I list webapp extensions using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I need to remove a Site Extension across ~50 Azure App Services.
The az webapp command space doesn't list anything for Site Extensions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest

The Azure team won't touch Site Extensions: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7617

However, a comment shows it's possible to delete the extension, if you know the resource ID: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7617#issuecomment-952743871

This command does not return installed extensions:

```
az resource list --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites
```

And this command returns nothing:

```
az resource list --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions
```

So how can I get a list of installed webapp extensions with Azure CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even Iam unable to get the Extensions list with `az resource list --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites` command.

[image]

Instead of `az resource list` use show `az resource show`.

```cs
az resource show --resource-group 'YourRGName' --resource-type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions'  --name 'mywebapp15June/siteextensions'
```

[image]

- This command work only if we provide the webapp name. At a time, we can retrieve only 1 webapp.
- To retrieve the extensions for all the webapps, need to run the above command in loop.

I have tried to run the command in loop using `Bash`.

```cs
RG="YourRGName"
AppNames=$(az webapp list --resource-group $RG --query "[].name" -o tsv)

for AppName in $AppNames; do
    echo "WebApp: $AppName"
    
    extensions=$(az resource show --resource-group $RG --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions --name "$AppName/siteextensions")
    
    echo "Site Extensions:"
    echo $extensions.title
    echo "=========================="
done
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

The webapps which has extensions installed will be listed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebApps -List Site Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-site-extensions#code-try-0) REST API to pull the list of extensions installed in the specific webapp.

You Need to write a custom script using the above rest API in PowerShell.

Here is the sample script and please do modify it accordingly based on your requirement.

```html
Connect-AzAccount

$token = (Get-AzAccessToken).Token

$subcriptionId= "<SubscriptionId>"

$webapplist= Get-AzWebApp 

Write-output "List of webapp extensions installed:"

foreach ( $item in $webapplist) {

$url = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/' + $subcriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + $item.ResourceGroup + "/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/" + $item.Name + "/siteextensions?api-version=2022-03-01"
 
$extension= Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers @{'authorization'= "Bearer " + $token } -ContentType "application/json" | Select -ExpandProperty Content
$installedextenstions = (ConvertFrom-Json $extension).value.name


Write-Output $installedextenstions

}
```